# ASP.NET Core Web API template with AAD authentication - where is a tutorial to make it work?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created new web service using VS 2019 ASP.NET Core Web API from the project template with AAD authenticalion. It creates a simple ValuesController and sets up AzureAdBearer authentication in StartUp, but there is no pointers of what do next. There are no doc links in the created project, and no comments. I could not find any documents on https://learn.microsoft.com/ referring this template, all examples there refer to other sample projects, which use different code constructs, authentication types, etc.

Out of the box, the project simply returns 401, whether run locally or published to Azure Web Service.

Is there any guidance on what to do next and make this template work?

Comment: Can you provide the template link?

Comment: You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code for AAD authentication samples with detailed steps.

Comment: Not sure how to provide the template link. It is VS2019 | Create New Project | Asp.Net Core Web application | API | Change Authentication | Work and School Accounts

Comment: I was able to run the following project end-2-end: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore

It uses a code that is very similar to the template with just a few tweaks. Now I need to adapt it to my actual REST API service that I have written.

Thanks everybody who answered (I don't have enough reputation to add points, unfortunately).

Answer (score 2):

A WebApi is out on the internet waiting for a client to call it with an access token in its headers.

Usually, to learn about this scenario, you would create a couple of projects in Visual Studio, a Web Api and a client app of some sort that calls this web api.

The client app will request an [access_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) for this web api from Azure AD and sent it along in its call to the api.

The generated code validates this access token to ensure that [its a valid one and issued for this Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) (among other things).

I'd suggest you try one of Please use the samples provided at [Azure Active Directory Home page for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)

Comment: Thanks, Kalyan! I was going to try one of the projects of Jean-Marc Prieur referred there. This one looks promising:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API

Thing is, the code there is looking very different from the VS2019 template I was trying to use. I am just surprised, that VS2019 ships with templates that have no working samples for it, so they are basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to code sample :  [Calling a web API in an ASP.NET Core web application using Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) .

Your web api is now protected by Azure AD , if any client call your api , it should append [Azure AD Access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) as a Bearer token to the Authorization header in an HTTP request . Your web api will validate the token and authorizes the user using the JWT bearer authentication middleware(`AzureAdBearer` middleware) .

Your client app could uses the OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.NET) to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol. Then the client app can use that token to access your protected API . See `TodoListWebApp` project .

Comment: Thanks, I was going to go through one of the more recent projects by the same guy:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/
I just hoped I could use a template as is or find some docs that explains how to use it.